# Using an array with arguments to instantiate a class, javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this class:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

I have this array with arguments

```
var args = ['Jane', 'Smith'];
```

Is there anyway to instantiate the class with this array? I don't want to change my class if possible.

```
//Doing this somehow:
var person = new Person(args)
```

https://jsbin.com/xuyawunoko/edit?js,console